# Amazon machine images and licensing

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I browsed Amazon Machine Images (AMI) available at Amazon for using VM in the cloud, and found some machines containing Visual Studio 2008 and Office. I wonder how it this possible to offer. These are all products that must be purchased. Perhaps I misunderstand something, but in case I purchase an AMI for EC2 with Office, what kind of license I get?

In addition, here is what Amazon explains about using Windows software:

Q. Can I use my existing Windows Server license with EC2?
No, Microsoft Windows Server licensing does not currently support using your existing Windows license in Amazon EC2 or any other cloud environment. We encourage you to work with your Microsoft account representative to understand licensing options.

Q. What software licenses can I bring to the Windows environment?
Specific software license terms vary from vendor to vendor. Therefore, we recommend that you check the licensing terms of your software vendor to determine if your existing licenses are authorized for use in Amazon EC2.

OK, with Windows it's clear. But what about other MS products: SQL Server, SharePoint, Visual Studio, BizTalk etc. Can they be installed on Amazon EC2 machines? I can't find anything on this matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you discussed this with Amazon? That would appear to be the logical first step.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is supported on Amazon EC2's Windows servers. Also, they're testing out the bring-your-own-Windows-license thing.

http://aws.amazon.com/windows/

You could certainly install other apps like SharePoint, Visual Studio, etc., but you'd want to be very careful about ensuring you have proper licensing for each instance you fire up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After looking at pricing with SQL Server (http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) this makes more sense: additional commerical components add to the price.

Unfortunately "bring your onw Windows license" is currently available only for US companies (accoring to http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/windows-license-mobility-pilot/), and we are in Norway.